# Android studio visibilidad de objetos

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas. Recién arranco en el mundo de desarrollo móvil, estoy intentando hacer una app sencilla. Tiene un par de `ImageView` las cuales con un botón quiero ir poniendo visibles o ocultarlas. Si pulso el botón 1 vez se pone visible la primer imagen, si pulso el botón otra vez quedaran visibles la primera y la segunda imagen y así en sucesivamente.

El problema es que al presionar directamente se ponen visibles todas las imágenes a la vez.

```
public void mostrar_contadores ()
{
        ImageView fosforo1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ImageView fosforo2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        ImageView fosforo3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        ImageView fosforo4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        ImageView fosforo5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);

    switch (contador1) {
        case 0: {
            fosforo1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            fosforo2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            fosforo3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            fosforo4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            fosforo5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        case 1:
            fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fosforo2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            fosforo3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            fosforo4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            fosforo5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        case 2:{
            fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fosforo2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fosforo3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            fosforo4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            fosforo5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        case 3:{
            fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fosforo2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fosforo3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fosforo4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            fosforo5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        case 4:{
            fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fosforo2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fosforo3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fosforo4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fosforo5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        case 5:{
            fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fosforo2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fosforo3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fosforo4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fosforo5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //BOTONES
    Button btnmas1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmas1);
    btnmas1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            suma_contador1();
        }
    });

    ImageView fosforo1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    fosforo1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    ImageView fosforo2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    fosforo2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    ImageView fosforo3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    fosforo3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    ImageView fosforo4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    fosforo4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    ImageView fosforo5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    fosforo5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

public void suma_contador1(){
    if (contador1<30) {
        contador1++;
        mostrar_contadores();
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloca el código del eventos de los botones.

Comment: Pues yo lo que veo de entrada es que en tu switch a cada case le hace falta un break, entonces si entra en alguno de los casos, va a hacer todos :S quiza ese sea el fallo.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que las opciones del switch no terminan, al entrar a una opción continua con la siguiente, tienes que agregar un `break;` para terminar cada opción.

```
switch (contador1) {
    case 0: {
        fosforo1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        fosforo2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        fosforo3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        fosforo4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        fosforo5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    break;
    case 1:
        fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fosforo2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fosforo3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fosforo4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        fosforo5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     break;
    case 2:{
        fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fosforo2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fosforo3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        fosforo4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        fosforo5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    break;
    case 3:{
        fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fosforo2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fosforo3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fosforo4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        fosforo5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
     break;
    case 4:{
        fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fosforo2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fosforo3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fosforo4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fosforo5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    break;
    case 5:{
        fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fosforo2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fosforo3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fosforo4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fosforo5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
     break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: No deberías añadir el `break;` al final de cada case? Y añadir un `default` quizá!

Comment: Hola Miquel estaba editando mi respuesta, primero pegue su código y luego lo edité, estoy escribiendo desde un pequeño móvil ya te imaginaras! =)

Comment: Ostras perdona! No me he fijado que estaba recién respondida haha. ¡Buena respuesta! Estoy convenicod que eso lo solucionará (no hacen falta los brackets `{}`si no me equivoco, aunque se pueden poner (pero no me gustan, tema d estilo...) si ya hay un break es fácil ver dónde empieza y termina :)

Comment: Gracias Miquel, como comentas no hacen falta los braquets, solo que copié el código del OP para mantener su código, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede es que para poder finalizar una operación dentro de un switch ésta debe de llevar un break; al final. Esto es usado para indicar que la acción ha terminado y si no lo posee toda acción encerrada en un switch se ejecutará hasta la última:

```
switch (contador1) {
case 0: {
    fosforo1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    fosforo2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    fosforo3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    fosforo4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    fosforo5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
break;
case 1:
    fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fosforo2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    fosforo3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    fosforo4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    fosforo5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 break;
case 2:{
    fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fosforo2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fosforo3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    fosforo4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    fosforo5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
break;
case 3:{
    fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fosforo2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fosforo3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fosforo4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    fosforo5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
 break;
case 4:{
    fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fosforo2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fosforo3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fosforo4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fosforo5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
break;
case 5:{
    fosforo1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fosforo2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fosforo3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fosforo4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fosforo5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
 break;
```

}